# how to avoid html design break up when use / after page name?

Tags: php, html

When I used index.php/ or  any page name then / in url bar. my full design is breaking up and also any images are not loading in to my web pages.

guys please suggest me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `/` after your page url, the website will think that the current directory is `index.php/` and that it is viewing the page `index.php/index.php`, because `index.php` pages are viewed as default if no other page is specified.

So what is happening, if you link your css with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="style.css"`, the website will look for the `style.css` in `index.php/style.css`, and the same with the images

Comment: That explains what's happening - but not how to fix it, for instance referencing css/images to the docroot (e.g. `/style.css`) ;)